# PowerShell displaying proper output data from HandBrakeCLI inside FileSystemWatcher

Tags: powershell, output, filesystemwatcher

I'm working on a simple script that monitors a folder for large video files and if it's larger then the set size it should send it to HandBrake to convert.

The main function of the script is done and works more or less but I am having trouble displaying proper output from HandBrake.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
$Folder             = "E:\Series"                                   #Folder to be monitored for large video files.
$Output             = "E:\Encoded"                                  #Folder where encoding jobs go to, and that will be monitored for completed jobs to replace the original file with.
$MaxMB          = "15"                                          #Max MB a minute
$MI_CLI         = "C:\Program Files\MediaInfoCLI\MediaInfo.exe" #Location oo MediaInfoCLI
$HB_CLI             = "C:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe" #Location of HandBrakeCLI
$HB_Container       = "Copy"                                        #HandBrake container output


$Filter             = '*.*'     
Write-Host "Monitoring "
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $Folder, $Filter 
$fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = $true          
Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Changed -SourceIdentifier FileUpdated -Action {
    Start-Sleep -s 1
    $FilePath =  $EventArgs.FullPath
    $FileName =  $FilePath.split('\')[-1]
    if($FilePath -imatch '\.(?:mp4|mkv)'){
        if((Test-Path -LiteralPath $filePath) -and -not (Test-Path -LiteralPath "$Output\$FileName")){
            if(Test-FileReady $FilePath){
                $fileSize = (Get-Item $FilePath).length
                if($fileSize -ge 734003200){
                    Write-Host ""
                    Write-Host "Large Video Detected: `"$($FileName)`""
                    Write-Host "Sending To HandBrake..."
                    HB-Convert $FilePath $Output
                }
             }
         }
    }
}


function HB-Convert{
    param ([parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$source,[parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$dest)
    if(-not (Test-Path $source) -or -not (Test-Path $dest)) {return}
    $FileName =  $source.split('\')[-1]
    start-process $HB_CLI -ArgumentList "-i `"$source`" -t 13 --angle 1 -c 1 -o `"$dest\$FileName`"  -f mkv  -w 1280 --crop 0:0:0:0 --loose-anamorphic  --modulus 2 -e x265 -q 20 --vfr -a 1 -E copy -6 dpl2 -R Auto -B 160 -D 0 --gain 0 --audio-fallback ac3 --encoder-preset=faster  --verbose=0 2> log.txt" -wait -nonewwindow
    #HandBrakeCLI -i `"$source`" -t 13 --angle 1 -c 1 -o `"$dest\$FileName`"  -f mkv  -w 1280 --crop 0:0:0:0 --loose-anamorphic  --modulus 2 -e x265 -q 20 --vfr -a 1 -E copy -6 dpl2 -R Auto -B 160 -D 0 --gain 0 --audio-fallback ac3 --encoder-preset=faster  --verbose=0 2> log.txt
}


function Test-FileReady {
        Param([parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$path)
        if (Test-Path  -LiteralPath $path) {
            trap {
                return $false
            }
            $stream = New-Object system.IO.StreamReader $path
            if ($stream) {
                $stream.Close()
                return $true
            }
        }
}
```

Now in **HB-Convert function** I have 2 lines that call HandBrakeCLI.
one through **Start-Process**
and one using **HandBrakeCLI**(I have added handbrake dir to my system environment variable)
the latter one is now marked out.

When I would call HB-Convert(Using HandBrakeCLI not Start-Process) manually in the command prompt everything works like it should I only get the progress of handbrake displayed.

> Encoding: task 1 of 1, 74.66 % (26.78 fps, avg 47.17 fps, ETA
>   00h05m40s)

Now when this is called through the FileSystemWatcher It will not display anything from handbrake it will only show output from the script it self

> Large Video Detected: "FileName"
>   Sending To HandBrake...

it will hang there till the encoding is done

now when FileSystemWatcher calls HB-Convert with start-process handbrake will output all data not just the progress witch is very annoying.

so how would I get it to display only the progress when its called true the FileSystemWatcher.

I have been trying to get it to work for hours its driving me nuts. hope some one here can fix it.
I only learned a bit of  PS for this so when I say that I am a nub  in PS thats a understatement :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it to work

adding this to the script

```
function global:HB-UpdateProgress{
  Process{
    $position = $host.ui.rawui.cursorposition
    $position.X = 0
    $host.ui.rawui.cursorposition = $position
    Write-Host @($input)[0] -NoNewline
  }
}
```

then use it as a pipeline when calling HandBrakeCLI will display the output properly